# Field with @Version annotation not being sent to frontend

Tags: java, spring, jpa, version, spring-data-jpa

I have an object with a property called version with `@Version` annotation. When retrieving this object from the database and sending it to the front end the version field is missing. Is there some special configuration you need to have to retrieve the object from the database and send it to the frontend? I am using java and spring on the backend. The field in the database is being updated so that part works but for some reason the version field isn't being sent to the front end.

Here are the relevant imports for my domain class:

```
import javax.persistence.Version;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

Here is the relevant code from my domain entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Table(schema = "schema", name = "type")
public class Type {
    @Column(name = "title", length = 128, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    String title;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 128, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    String description;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    int version = 0;

    //getters and setters

    public void setVersion(int version)
    {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public int getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant rest controller imports:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

Here is the Rest Controller Method that sends the entity to the client:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/type", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Type> listTypes() {
    ArrayList<Type> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Type>(TypeService.loadTypes());
    Type type = list.get(0);
    return list;
}
```

EDIT: I found that the field gets sent if I remove the `@Version` annotation

Comment: Please, post your POJO code.

Comment: @JoseRamonGarcia added POJO

Comment: your code to retrieve the object from database is what? and what SQL is issued to retrieve it? and is the version set there? and on with the debugging process ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realized of your text "but for some reason the version field isn't being sent to the front end"

Please post the code where you send the POJO to the frontend.

Comment: @JoseRamonGarcia posted

Comment: Everything appears to be ok. Are you using Jackson as JSON encoding library?

As a workaround (yes, I know...), you can create another field, called "version2" or something like that, and copy the "version" value in the "setVersion" method. The "version2" will be serialized to JSON.

Comment: @JoseRamonGarcia I am using Jackson, and I will implement the workaround until another solution comes up. I added more relevant imports